# Dropdown... recursive problem / dropdown without data validation possible?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, filter, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 columns: (example)

- Column A: elements for the dropdown
- Column B: "VIP" selection
- Column C: "normal User" selection

The dropdown in Column B simply has all elements of Column A.

The dropdown in Column C however should only have the remaining elements of Column A (=> not selected In B or C)

I was able to do that by creating a Column (lets call it D) where only elements are added that are in Column A but not in Column B or C and using the data validation for Column C on this Column D. The Problem is ofc this is recursive...so as soon as I enter something in Column C it gets removed from Column D and is no longer valid in column C (but for this Cell it should be)

So I think there are only 3 options to solve this...

- don't use recursion (but I don't know how to solve my problem then)
- disable the warning from the data validation (would be fine for me but as far as I know not possible?)
- create a dropdown without using the data validation (don't know how/if that is possible)

I hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I made a filter for every row with all remaining values ("Column C - Column A - Column B") for that row by using the following formula and simply adding the value in Column B from that row again at the end to that filter. (values are Column E - M) 
`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE({FILTER($D$3:$D$11, ISNA(MATCH($D$3:$D$11, $A$3:$A$11, 0)), ISNA(MATCH($D$3:$D$11, $B$3:$B$11, 0)));B3}),"")`

The dropdown in Column B is now Column E - Column M (end Column depends on how many possible values you have)

(for B3 it would be E3:M3),

(for B6 it would be E6:M6), ...

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9UVb.jpg (sry I'm not allowed to post a picture.I hope the link will still be available...)

Answer (score 0):

you could solve this with 2 side columns which you can then hide. column **E** will feed the dropdown of **A1** and **B1**. and then column **F** will feed **C1** where **F2** will contain:

```
=FILTER(E2:E, E2:E<>A1, E2:E<>B1)
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YM7Xa-YAnqeF954ueSEnphIZTBcyXjUaMaMq3rc8SeQ/copy)

Comment: I don't really understand your solution.
In your example Column A is my "VIP" and Column C I think would be my "normal" but what is Column B?
And if I expand that to more than just one row it doesn't remove the input from row 1 into C2. 

I made a quick [Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fctWyoRmsLuMRWAxM8Rnrnlpr7WMyB5raZYHeiLsrRo/edit#gid=0) how my sheet looks like